# Gvim GLib-GObject-WARNING in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: vim, gvim, glib

I upgraded from ubuntu 13.04 to ubuntu 13.10 this afternoon. And when I try starting vim form the terminal after the upgrade, I get these warnings

```
(gvim:4054): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(gvim:4054): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(gvim:4054): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(gvim:4054): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised`
```

How can I fix these and what exectly are these warnings about

Comment: This happens too in xubuntu, lubuntu and ubuntu 13.10 and it's been reported as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/1241917)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was seeing this in 14.04. But I only had vim-gnome installed.
Removing vim-gnome and installing vim-gtk works without any error messages.

```
sudo apt-get -y remove vim-gnome
sudo apt-get install vim-gtk
```

Answer (score 28):

This doesn't fix your issue, but I tried removing and installing vim-gnome and had the same problem.
So, I removed vim-gnome and installed vim-gtk and it works fine.

Answer (score 7):

For solving this, I added an alias to run gvim with all stderr messages discarded.

Just add the following line to your `.bashrc` file:

```bash
alias gvim="gvim 2>/dev/null"
```

I hate these types of errors and warnings when the program I'm using is beyond my control and it prints a lot of these which distract me from what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

After checking your suggestions I learned that I had **both** vim-gnome and vim-gtk installed.

This issue was solved for me by removing vim-gnome and simply keeping vim-gtk.